# Typescript import statement

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

I am trying to understand what different syntax[es](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/65544/12177) of `import` does and when I need to use them.

I am using typescript 1.6 (latest version as of now).

I have seen several examples of doing an import.  One looks like this:

```
import {Aurelia} from "aurelia-framework";
```

Which gives me access to `Aurelia` from the Aurelia Framework.  I more or less get this one, but I am unsure what where the part in the quotes is looking up from.

Here is another one that resharper inserted into my code:

```
import myJsServiceActions = require("../../service_actions/myJsFile");
```

This also gives me access to the stuff in myJsFile.  But the syntax is quite different.  And this one seems to be a path reference in the quotes.

Also this one does not use the curly braces {} like the first one.  When I try to put in something like {ServiceActions} (a module in that file) it gives an error on the `require` saying that a string literal is expected.

**What is different about this second usage (from the first one)?**

I have also seen these usages in the internet, but I am assuming they are just older syntax (if they are still used please indicate how they are different):

```
/// <reference path="myModules.d.ts" />
....
import gt = module('greeter');
```

---

And last, how does it find the stuff in the quotes?  I tried this:

```
import breeze from "breeze";
```

and I get the error:

> Cannot find module "breeze"

But in my config.js these are defined right next to eachother:

```
map: {
    //....
    "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@0.18.0",
    "breeze": "npm:breeze-client@1.5.5",
   //.....
  }
```

**It seems to me that if the import of aurelia-framework works, then breeze should work too.**  But I assume that is my ignorance of how 'import' works that is causing the problem.

Comment: You mentioned "config.js" what is that? Are you talking about tsconfig.json?

Comment: @gilamran - I am not sure what it is, but it seems to manage my dependencies.  It is created when I do a `jspm init`.  I assumed it was a common web development dependency manager.   Something that let you reference things by a nice name (breeze) instead of the full name (breeze-clinet@1.5.5.)

Comment: jspm uses systemjs to manage all the dependencies of your app, and load them when needed. It is not related to typescript.

Answer (score 2):

> where the part in the quotes is looking up from.

- First anything that has `declare module "aurelia-framework"`
- Then depending on the module resolution either a file `aurelia-framework` up the directory tree (`classic` module resolution) or [Node style lookup](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) up the directory tree (if `--module commonjs` or explicit node module resolution).

> Here is another one that resharper inserted into my code:

Relative files imports are relative `.d.ts` or `.ts` or `.tsx` imports.

## More

> `import foo from "foo"` vs `import foo = require('foo')`

The first is ES6 style import (as supported by ES6) and the second is `nodejs` style import (modeled after `var foo = require('foo')`)

> `import breeze from "breeze";`

You probably want to do `import * as breeze from "breeze"`

Comment: import * as breeze from "breeze" did the trick for me. I had to wrap breeze into quotes ('breeze') in the "declare module" definition in breeze.d.ts. It's kinda hacky because on a new machine the pulled definition wont have the quote wrap. But without the quotes it complains that it cannot find module "breeze".